# CloudFormation template for AWS API Gateway + Swagger Codegen?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jax-rs, swagger, aws-cloudformation, swagger-codegen

Was hoping someone has come across similar scenario:

We have an existing CloudFormation template (in yaml) for creating our AWS API resource. The Swagger definition is embedded into the CF template under the body field of AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi.

The Swagger definition contains AWS integration specific fields along side with CF parameter placeholders.

What is the best approach to use the Swagger Codegen tool for generating backend interfaces / data objects? (Java + JAX-RS 2.X).

I'm thinking we might need to decouple the Swagger definition with the CF template somehow. Or perhaps there is something more straight forward?

Comment: Are you building any Cloudformation infrastructure via CI ie Jenkins? Why not build a job that generates Open API via Swagger Codegen and inject its output into the CFN template.

Comment: Yes, we are using Bamboo.

Are you able to elaborate further? Our Open API spec is embedded in the current CF template which contains AWS specific fields and params. I'm not sure how Swagger Codegen can help in this case? My understanding is to use Codgen for our backend stub (which is what we want), it doesn't generate the Open API spec.

Comment: I would create a CI job that takes all the params, then calls the Codegen to generate the embedded swagger definition, and generates the CFN template, and the creates/updates the stack.

Comment: Ah ok, I think you must be referring to a bottom up approach using swagger core (not codegen tool). Interesting suggestion, we will look into this, thanks!